# Change BIOS Settings (Enable Secure Boot) on Toshiba and Dynabook with Powershell

Tags: powershell, bios, toshiba-laptop

I am trying to write a Powershell script to enable Secure Boot on a Dynabook Tecra BIOS, I have written another two for HP and Lenovo and they are working fine. The script that is listed in the Dynabook [WMI documentaion](https://aps2.support.emea.dynabook.com/kb0/TSB3803HR0000R06_TOSHIBA_BIOS_WMI_InterfaceGuide_rev1.5b.pdf) is not working for me and the method SetBiosSettings is throwing error 2147749986 which means *"One of the parameters to the call is not correct. The system supports the subfunction but the subfunction is called with the invalid input arguments."* but I have passed the arguments as specified in the Docs.

Here is an overview of the code that I am trying to run:

```sh
$read = gwmi -namespace "root\wmi" -class "BiosSetting" | where {$_.InstanceName -match "ACPI\PNP0C14\0_0"} # also tried to switch InstanceName to "ACPI\PNP0C14\0_2" and the same error code occurred
$read.setBiosSetting("SecureBoot,Enabled;")`
```

Comment: Hi @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle, I have already tried that but it throws "cannot find an overload for "SetBiosSetting" and the argument count "2" " I also tried to pass up to 5 additional arguments but faced with the same error.

Comment: Here's how I got it to work on HP in case any of this helps with syntax & format for Levono which I don't have access to test: https://i.imgur.com/V1D9g2F.png. No that's not the password I use and I was using it for testing once and nothing production so password in scripts are bad. Since I used `out-null` there, I suspect I was suppressing something, check to ensure that the settings do not toggle even though the command line spits an error just in case it's benign but still changes the firmware setting. Might just need to tweak the where condition a bit, confirm output that line as expected

Comment: Hi @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle, your code for Lenovo is very similar to mine, and it is working fine, but the issue is with Toshiba and Dynabook, the code in the WMI Interface Docs is not working for me and I have tested it on a Toshiba and a Dynabook where the Toshiba machine has an old BIOS version and the Dynabook has a recent version but the same error is occurring. After digging into the function's code I clarified that I was passing the parameters correctly and yet it is not working. I have also checked if it is changing the settings even though I was prompted with an error but it is not.

Comment: What  do you get if you run just this: `gwmi –namespace "root\wmi" -Class "QueryBiosSettings" | ForEach-Object {if($_.CurrentSetting -ne ""){Write-Host $_.CurrentSetting}}`? From that document I also see `"ACPI\\pnp0c14\\0.0"` using but for `gwmi -Namespace "root\wmi" -Class "ModeControl"` perhaps that's all you need it to use those values and with that class more specifically. So perhaps `-Class "QueryBiosSettings"` or `-Class "ModeControl"` using `"ACPI\\pnp0c14\\0.0"` in the `where` filter with the `ModeControl` class there tho.

Comment: `"SecureBoot,Enabled;"` has to be 2 separate arguments like your error indicates: `"SecureBoot","Enabled"`